# Circular Dependencies in TypeScript with State Pattern

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency, state-pattern

I am implementing the State design pattern in TypeScript and have run into circular dependency issues between `Context`, `State`, and state classes (`StateA` and `StateB`).

```
// context.ts
import { State } from "./state";

export class Context {
    private state: State;

    constructor(state: State) {
        this.transitionTo(state);
    }

    public transitionTo(state: State): void {
        console.log(`Context: Transition to ${(<any>state).constructor.name}.`);
        this.state = state;
        this.state.setContext(this);
    }

    public request1(): void {
        this.state.handle1();
    }

    public request2(): void {
        this.state.handle2();
    }
}

// state.ts`
import { Context } from "./context";

export abstract class State {
    protected context: Context;

    public setContext(context: Context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public abstract handle1(): void;
    public abstract handle2(): void;
}

// stateA.ts
import { State } from "./state";
import { StateB } from "./stateB";

export class StateA extends State {
    public handle1(): void {
        console.log('StateA handles request1.');
        console.log('StateA wants to change the state of the context.');
        this.context.transitionTo(new StateB());
    }

    public handle2(): void {
        console.log('StateA handles request2.');
    }
}

// stateB.ts
import { State } from "./state";
import { StateA } from "./stateA";

export class StateB extends State {
    public handle1(): void {
        console.log('StateB handles request1.');
    }

    public handle2(): void {
        console.log('StateB handles request2.');
        console.log('StateB wants to change the state of the context.');
        this.context.transitionTo(new StateA());
    }
}
```

The `StateA` and `StateB` classes switch back and forth between each other, leading to a circular dependency. Also, the `Context` class imports `State`, and `State` imports `Context`.
I expect to have 5-10 states and ~10 requests which the states have different implementations for.

I have tried restructuring the code, but have not been able to find a way that would avoid circular dependencies. I also tried `import type` within the `stateA` and `stateB` classes, but that doesn't work because they create a new instance of that type.

Comment: Did you think about putting the abstract class `State` and  class `Context` in one file? In my opinion it is perfectly okay to do this, because of these classes are strongly related to each other and cannot exist without the other class.
My suggestion would be to create a file `context.ts` with a default export of class `Context` and a named export for the abstract class `State`.